# Creating a loop for different random forest training algorithms

Tags: r, random-forest

Im trying to write a for loop to create various random forest models. I've stored the variables I would like to use in the different models in a list called list:

```
 list <- c("EXPG1 + EXPG2", "EXPG1 + EXPG2 + distance")
```

Then I try to loop over it created predictions. What I finally want to achieve is this:

```
modFit1 <- train(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2, data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)
modFit2 <- train(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2 + distance, data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)
```

I have some issues trying to accomplish this however.

This doesn't work:

```
modFit1 <- train(won ~ list[1], data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)
```

And also this doesnot seem to do the trick:

```
for (R in modfits) {

  modfit <- paste0("won ~ ", R, ", data=training, method=\"rf\", prox=\"TRUE")
 train(modfit)

}
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong?

Comment: Maybe this could help `?as.formula`?

Comment: It seems to work but then I cant call predict on it... Any more suggestions? There should be a way for this I assume

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list to store the model in first

```
results <- vector('list',2)
list <- c("EXPG1 + EXPG2", "EXPG1 + EXPG2 + distance")

for (i in 1:2){
  results[i] <- train(won ~ list[i], data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)
}
```

Then you should be able to call `predict` on `results[[1]]`