# Train a random forest algorithm using various columns

Tags: r, random-forest

I have asked this question before here:  [Creating a loop for different random forest training algoritms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678882/creating-a-loop-for-different-random-forest-training-algoritms?noredirect=1#comment57103022_34678882) but didnt get a right answer yet. So hereby another attempt with a more reproducable example.

I have the following datasets:

```
train <- read.csv(url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/course/Kaggle/train.csv"))
test <- read.csv(url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/course/Kaggle/test.csv"))
train <- train[complete.cases(train), ]
```

I would like to run several random forest algoritms to see which one performs best. So what I basically want to do is:

```
#predict based on Pclass
fit <- randomForest(as.factor(Survived) ~ Pclass, data=train, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)
Prediction <- predict(fit, test)
#fetch accuracy


#predict based on Pclass and Sex
fit <- randomForest(as.factor(Survived) ~ Pclass + Sex, data=train, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)
Prediction <- predict(fit, test)
#fetch accuracy
```

I would like to create some kind of loop so that I can store all values in a list and then loop over it. So like this:

```
list <- c(Pclass, Pclass + Sex)


for (R in list) {
  modfit <- paste0("won ~ ", R, ", data=training, method=\"rf\", prox=\"TRUE")
  modfit <- as.formula(modfit)
 train(modfit)
 }
```

But the code above doesn't work. It gives me the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
<text>:1:13: unexpected ','
1: won ~ Pclass,
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (R in list) {
 modfit <- paste0("won ~ ", R, "data=training, method=\"rf\", prox=\"TRUE")
 modfit <- as.formula(modfit)
 train(modfit)
 }
```

You might be having a comma before data=training that does not need to be there